# Upgrade Desktop form 14.04 LTS "No new release found"

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

I've verified that "Notify me of new Ubuntu version" is set to "For long-term support versions" in Software & Updates. Yet when I run do-release-upgrade I get "No new release found." Please help.

[image: Software Update Settings]

Comment: running do-release-upgrade -c from command line I still get "No new release found.".

Comment: Oddly, I was able to upgrade to 16.04.1 when I switched from long term to latest/regular even when 16.10 is available.

Answer (score 4):

Command `do-release-upgrade -c -d` at this moment will get 16.04 LTS

Comment: What's the `-c` option? It isn't listed in http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/do-release-upgrade.8.html

Comment: -c option show current available release

Comment: @DavidFoerster Excuse me, do you know why `do-release-upgrade` without `-d` says “No new release found”? Is it a devel release?

Comment: @Daniyal: This (the comment section of an answer) is not the right place to ask a different question. Please [ask a new question](/questions/ask) instead.

Comment: It looks like -c is a check option to just print the release that would be taken.  No instell will happen with that option set but it is very useful to see what you would get.  The -d option tells the command to look for development releases too (and if you are on LTS that means development LTS ones only).  Could you update this answer to highlight those points and make it clean that a second command will be need to install what is presented at the prompt?

Comment: @muru the `-c` or `--check-dist-upgrade-only` option is to "Check only if a new distribution release is available and report the result via the exit code." It and other options can be viewed by issuing `do-release-upgrade -h`

Answer (score 4):

Usually, LTS upgrades are not supported in the initial LTS-next. That is, 12.04LTS could not be upgraded to 14.04LTS, but only when 14.04.1LTS was released. I would expect the same to be true this time, and that you'll have to wait until 16.04.1 to be released. I don't know the planned release date, but it's usually about three months after the main release.

You ***will*** be notified when it's ready to be upgraded and you should not try to do it manually by entering commands unless you really know what you're doing. Upgrading LTS to LTS is more difficult than normal upgrades and for most people, it's more important, so this needs more time to be handled correctly.

The ".1"-releases are Ubuntus version of "Service packs". So in other words, wait until the first SP is released. I would guess it'll happen sometime in July.

Answer (score 3):

As of 9th May this still does not work

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

But it worked for me with -d flag.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Answer (score 1):

the 16.04 LTS Final Release is not out yet. it will be released during sometime later today/tomorrow latest. try again then

Answer (score 1):

The 16.04 LTS Final Release is not out for upgrade yet but it will be released sometime later today/tomorrow.

To have a check you can simply do from terminal

```
do-release-upgrade -c
```

this will check if the actual release is open. If yes run the command

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

without any parameter.

Comment: May 1st: still not available.

Comment: May 31st: I'm still getting "no new release found" :(

Answer (score 0):

The LTS versions only upgrade to LTS by default. Which the new LTS has not hit the mirrors yet.

Strangely I got 16.04 Ubuntu Mate for Raspberry Pi yesterday.

Comment: The raspberry pi version is maintained by a different team, they probably just did it early